# Error: "Traceback (most recent call last):"

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I'm trying to install `pip` to my pycharm, I'm using Mac OS X version 10.11.1

I tried: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==7.1.0
```

I'm stuck a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify your system python. Instead, install a new version of python with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). And then create a new env for each project use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or venv if you are using py3k.